# Как запретить вставлять перенос строки после блока с комментариями перед use в PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

Есть код:

```php
...

/**
 * Repositories
 */
use App\Repositories\User\UserRepository;

...
```

После форматирования:

```php
...

/**
 * Repositories
 */

use App\Repositories\User\UserRepository;

...
```

**PhpStorm**: **2020.2.4**

Как запретить вставлять перенос строки после блока комментариев?

Answer (score 0):

Для запрета добавления переноса строки после блока с комментариями и перед `use` необходимо установить значение `0` в `File`->`Settings`->`Editor`->`Code Style`->`Php`, далее вкладка `Blank Lines` и  там параметр `Before 'Use' statements`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]